# Number of passenger in a station

Tags: openttd

Number of passenger depends on the number of surrounding building or the roads too? If I remove roads around station and building will be built instead of roads, will it increase the number of passengers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the amount of passengers come from the buildings in the vicinity of the station. Removing unnecessary roads results in the town creating a building on that tile and adds extra passengers and mail to your station. Building size does matter too.

What i usually do is build the roads myself for the cities. This way you can lay down the road in a very efficient way and the town can grow faster since they do not need budget for roads. I usually create 8x2 rectangles this way and make sure i have a single tile open space between my station and the first road. It would look womething like below where S stands for station, G for grass/empty and R for road.

```
S,G,R,G,G,R,G
S,G,R,G,G,R,G
S,G,R,G,G,R,G
S,G,R,R,R,R,G
S,G,R,G,G,R,G
S,G,R,G,G,R,G
S,G,R,G,G,R,G
```

Comment: you mean this structure in 1-D?! S,R,B,B,R,B,B,R ?? {S=station, R=road, B=building}

Comment: btw I believe that building size, type has an effect on passengers come from them

Comment: I prefere 3x3 size

Comment: Maximum vanilla building size is 2x2 also less roads mean more buildings. One could go for 4x8 and keep destructing the roads inside that the city creates until it is full with 2x2 buildings. This is tedious but gives much more building per tile. in your 25 tiles you have 9 free tiles (.36 buildings per tile) in my 40 tiles i have 16 free tiles (.4 buildings per tile). Going with 4x8 would yield (.53 buildings per tile). The amount of roads really does not matter as long as a possible building has access to it.

Comment: I like your 8x2 system :-) what about bus stations? usually nearby the railway station I place bus stations with ctrl-click, but bus station is 7x7

Comment: Does not really matter, you could micro manage forever. Less roads mean more buildings, put your outer road just outside the square of influence of your stations.